# Dynamically generated certificates for ssl connections

Tags: ssl, c++11, windows-runtime, ssl-certificate

I am working on a Windows 8 app and I cannot package certificate as it is generated at run-time. Is it possible to use dynamically generated certificates? and if so can I use this at the Websocket/StreamSocket level?

Any reference to sample code will be very helpful (preferably C++)

Comment: Are you using it for client-side authentication or...?

Comment: Yes, I will need it for client-side authentication.

Comment: Generating PKI certificates at runtime doesn't actually make security sense. Who is going to trust them? And why should they? A PKI certificate is supposed to reliably identify a unique entity. Generation at runtime violates that.

Comment: @EJP, We have installed our product at the customer end. So we trust ourselves with this CSR request!

Answer (score 0):

RSA and other public key cryptography methods are generally secure, but they do rely on the validity of the public key.  As such, there are many certificate authorities that issue list public keys http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority .  When they do so, they "testify" that the key does indeed belong to the entity claiming to be the owner.  Issuing the key at runtime makes little sense, since it cannot be validated that the key is from this person.

Comment: The certificate is not signed by CA. It is signed by the customer for client side authentication. The customer has our software running which signs it.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question. Windows 8 metro api's doesn't support asymmetric keys in a csr. Refer here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464944.aspx

We cannot proceed unless they make a change or an openssl build for metro is available.

Update: There is also no way to retrieve public key of server's certificate during certificate exchange. As per the last update from Microsoft employee (May 2012) http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/bbffe488-fc74-4c8b-bed1-adf8fe162449/  this isn't a supported feature.